# Django admin: postgres DateTimeRangeField not displayed properly

Tags: django, django-admin

Some of my models have postgres-specific `django.contrib.postgres.fields.DateTimeRangeField`s, and those fields are exposed in the corresponding admin panels. I expected that the ranges forms would consist of two Django-style datetime pickers, with a separate one for the date part and a separate part for the time part (just like the `DateTimeField` would). However, I get two text inputs which expect input in a very particular format. Is there anything I am missing or have to configure separately?

The relevant code is:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import DateTimeRangeField
...

class MyModel(models.Model):
    time_off = DateTimeRangeField()
```

admin:

```
@register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [SplitDateTimeWidget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#splitdatetimewidget).

Simply change the admin part as:

```
class MyModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
          'time_off': RangeWidget(SplitDateTimeWidget())
        }


@register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelAdminForm
```

or use `formfield_overrides` to override the widget if you wish.

Comment: Thank you, that got me to four inputs, but I don't get the calendar icon and widget and the clock icon and widget that are present in the regular django DateTimeField's widget.

Comment: Tried AdminSplitDateTime, as it is the field that has the date and time pickers and did get the form I wanted, but now i get errors submitting it (list has no method strip()). I will look more into it.

Comment: @Ibolit yes, I tried `AdminSplitDateTime` and got this error too, I think we should do some kind of _hack_ on the value before submitting.

Comment: 3 years later, this is still not available. Still shows 4 text inputs instead of a proper `DateTimeWidget`. Also see https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27466 from 2016

Answer (score 1):

I used the following:

```
from django.contrib.admin import widgets as admin_widgets
from django.contrib.postgres import fields as pg
from django.contrib.postgres import forms as pg_widgets

@register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    formfield_overrides = {
        pg.DateRangeField: {
            'widget': pg_widgets.RangeWidget(admin_widgets.AdminDateWidget),
        },
    }
```

Works perfectly, with a calendar pop-up, 'today' button, and everything. This is for a `Date`, but you should get similar results with a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

To get this working I needed to combine both parts of the split datetimefield (to fix the "list has no method strip()" as other commentors had noted). Some additional validation should probably be present here to ensure "value" has the correct format.

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminSplitDateTime
from django.contrib.postgres.forms import RangeWidget, DateTimeRangeField
from django.forms import ModelForm

class CombinedDateTimeRangeField(DateTimeRangeField):
    def combine(self, value):
        if value:
            return [f"{value[0][0]}:{value[0][1]}", f"{value[1][0]}:{value[1][1]}"]
        return None

    def clean(self, value):
        value = self.combine(value)
        return super().clean(value)

    def has_changed(self, initial, data):
        data = self.combine(data)
        return super().has_changed(initial, data)

class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    time_off = CombinedDateTimeRangeField(widget=RangeWidget(AdminSplitDateTime))
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = "__all__"

@register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm
```